# React - change route from function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

My fetch function is sometimes returning errors. If that happens I would like to go to something like url/notfound and render NotFound component. Can it be done with react router? Are there any other ways to change route from function ?

Answer (score 1):

You can show something like this
I am showing ES6 example 

Let's assume that you have a state variable which updates `loadError` on `fetch` operations result

```
this.state={
   loadError:false
}
```

Like,

```
fetch(this.host+this.url,{method:"GET",redirect:"follow"}).then(()=>
     this.setState({loadError:true})      
)
```

somewhere in `render()` method

```
{loadError ? <Redirect to="/NotFound"/>}
```